# Django staticfiles.W004 warning when using os.path.join

Tags: python, django, os.path

I'm getting this warning:

> ?: (staticfiles.W004) The directory
> '/home/user/Desktop/Projects/project/project/project/static' in the
> STATICFILES_DIRS setting does not exist.

But only when I use this definition for the staticfiles dir

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static')]
```

If I use this instead

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = ['/home/user/Desktop/Projects/project/project/project/static']
```

I have no issue.

Comment: Is it necessary to include the ```/``` with ```static```?

Comment: the directory shown in the error is different from the hardcoded version

Comment: For it to work in the first example, you need the settings file inside /tradebot/tradebot  (not inside a subdirectory) and the static directory as a subdirectory inside /tradebot.  Is that what you've got?